# Javascript: How would you get the highest rated product category based on these 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Assuming I have 2 arrays:

```
const products = [
  {
    name: 'prod1',
    category: 'Meat'
  },
  {
    name: 'prod2',
    category: 'Meat'
  },
  {
    name: 'prod3',
    category: 'Dairy'
  }];


const rate = [
  {
    name: 'prod1',
    rate: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'prod2',
    rate: 36
  },
  {
    name: 'prod3',
    rate: 50,
  }];
```

How would you get the category that has the highest sum rate? For example, prod1 and prod2 share the same category 'Meat" and hence the rate for meat is 36 + 23 = 59.

The way I thought about it is to create an adjusted Array of products where each entry will contain the rate from the second array and then I will create a result array and push an object of category and sumRate after iterating the adjustedArray.

So if the result Array has an object with category, I would adjust the sum and add the new rate, if not I'll create a new entry with category: rate.

Can we do this in a very optimal way?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Consider that you're trying to maximize this function over products... `product => rate.find(r => r.name === product.name)?.rate;`

Comment: @danh Note that I wanna write a function that would rate the 2 arrays and simply return the category that has the highest sum of rates.

So it's more like grouping the products by category and then calculate the sum of rates for each product.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the grouping or with the maximization in the group?

Comment: @danh struggling how I can approach this solution in general. Grouping I can do reducer but how I can group by category and have a sum of each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP probably knows, canonical grouping goes like this...

```
const prodsByCategory = products.reduce((acc, p) => {
  let cat = p.category;
  if (!acc[cat]) acc[cat] = [];
  acc[cat].push(p);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Modify this a little to add the data which will be needed to optimize.

```
const prodsByCategory = products.reduce((acc, p) => {
  let cat = p.category;
  // instead of just an array, keep an array and a total
  if (!acc[cat]) acc[cat] = { products: [], totalRate: 0 };
  // instead of just pushing, push and increment total with a lookup
  acc[cat].products.push(p);
  acc[cat].totalRate += rateForProduct(p) || 0;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

We need a lookup for rateForProduct, like this:

```
const rateForProduct = product => {
  return rate.find(r => r.name === product.name)?.rate || 0;
}
```

That should produce an object keyed by category with values that have a prop called `totalRate`.  Sort those entries so that the first one is maximized. Here's a demo...

```js
const products = [{
    name: 'prod1',
    category: 'Meat'
  },
  {
    name: 'prod2',
    category: 'Meat'
  },
  {
    name: 'prod3',
    category: 'Dairy'
  }
];

const rate = [{
    name: 'prod1',
    rate: 23,
  },
  {
    name: 'prod2',
    rate: 36
  },
  {
    name: 'prod3',
    rate: 50,
  }
];

const rateForProduct = product => {
  return rate.find(r => r.name === product.name)?.rate || 0;
}

const prodsByCategory = products.reduce((acc, p) => {
  let cat = p.category;
  if (!acc[cat]) acc[cat] = {
    products: [],
    totalRate: 0
  };
  acc[cat].products.push(p);
  acc[cat].totalRate += rateForProduct(p);
  return acc;
}, {});

const sortedEntries = Object.entries(prodsByCategory).sort((a, b) => b[1].totalRate - a[1].totalRate);

const bestEntry = {
  category: sortedEntries[0][0],
  rate: sortedEntries[0][1].totalRate
}
console.log(bestEntry);
```